# Find Controllers which aren't in use

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controllers, asp.net-mvc-controller

Fairly new to this and as you cann tell learning - but basically my manager has thrown me in the deep end and I need a little help to swim - He wants me to create a list of all the controllers which aren't in use any more.

I can i determine this?
I've got a massive list and I don't know how to check.

Comment: You can't easily. You'll need to go though the code line by line or add logging, leave it run, then check it later.

Comment: The references are likely not hard references @user1490835. For example `@Action("action", "controller")` is essentially a reference to "controller" but it's not linked. If you removed this controller, it'd break. It's basically very "stringy".

Comment: The [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) addon for Visual Studio is helpful for this. Open the controller, rightclick the action, select "Find usages". There is a 30 days demo version available. Beware: this might still overlook some usages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution to this was to look through each control and search through the live projection Solution to see if the controller is referenced anywhere.